# Recieving 'Attempted import error" message in first MERN application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern

This is my first application I am building with the MERN stack and currently I am going through a tutorial. For some reason I cannot figure out the message :
Attempted import error: 'reducers' is not exported from './reducers'.
This is currently my code in my App.js:

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import { reducers } from "./reducers";

import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In the reducers file:
posts.js

```html
export default reducers = (posts = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_ALL":
      return action.payload;
    case "CREATE":
      return posts;
    default:
      return posts;
  }
};
```

index.js

```html
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import Post from "./posts";

export default combineReducers({ posts });
```

to get a better visual this is currently my screen:
[computer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1txD4.jpg)

Comment: You need to post your reducers.js file

Comment: Post the reducer file. You probably forgot the export keyword.

Comment: Updated posts. It would be from the reducers file, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In your `reducers/index.js`, you are exporting it as `default`. Therefore, if you want to import it in your `src/index.js`, you need to use `import reducers from "./reducers"` (with no curly braces).

Another approach is that you can use `export const reducers = combineReducers({ posts });` in `reducers/index.js`, then you don't need to modify `src/index.js`.

You can read more about the document on [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) in JavaScript.